# An example of unbounded isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $H, K$ are two Hilbert spaces,  $V: H\to K$ is an isometry if $V^*V=1$. Does there exist  a concrete eexample of a unbounded isometry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not exist such an example.

An isometry between Hilbert spaces is in particular an isometry as metric spaces. i.e. $\Vert V \Vert = 1$. Hence every isometry between Hilbert spaces is bounded.

---

An isometry preserves the norm since $\forall x \in H$

$$ \Vert A x \Vert^2 = \langle Ax, Ax \rangle = \langle A^*Ax , x \rangle = \langle x,x \rangle = \Vert x \Vert^2 $$

Comment: $V^*V=I$ does not imply that $V$ is unitary, unless the Hilbert space is finite-dimensional (in which case the question is moot, as all operators are bounded).

Comment: Absolutely true. Edited